# ERR_INSUFICIENT_RESOURCES loading data from a json file

Tags: javascript, php, json, performance, canvasjs

I´m having the next problem in my chrome console when this load 4 PHP files,I load the queries of this files to obtain 4 real time charts:

[image: err_insufficient]

The php files have the next code :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$con3 = mysqli_connect("p:localhost", "root", "", "");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
echo "Failed to connect to DataBase: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
$data_points = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ID,AccountID,time FROM tbhealth_temp     order by time"); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $point = array("value1" => $row['time'], "value2" => $row['TempValue']);
    array_push($data_points, $point);
}
echo json_encode($data_points);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And I draw the charts with the next code :

```
<script>
       var dataLength = 0;
            var data = [];
            var updateInterval = 40;
            function updateTemp() {
                $.getJSON("/data_temp.php", function (result) {
                    if (dataLength !== result.length) {
                        for (var i = dataLength; i < result.length; i++) {
                            data.push({
                                x: parseFloat(result[i].value1),
                                y: parseFloat(result[i].value2)
                            });
                        }
                        dataLength = result.length;
                        chart.render();
                    }
                });
            }
     var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart", {
                animationEnabled: true,
                zoomEnabled: true,
                panEnabled: true,
                title: {
                   text: "}Temp
                },
                axisX: {
                    tickThickness:0,
                    valueFormatString:" ",
                },
                axisY: {
                 maximum: 40.0,
                 minimum: 35.0,

                },
                data: [{
                color:"black",
                type:"spline", dataPoints: data}],
            });
            setInterval(updateTemp,updateInterval);

 </script>
```

Do you know what I have that error?, thanks for your attention.
Best regards.